# domain mapping: php or nodejs & nginx

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, dns, mapping

I want to automate a process so that my clients can sign up on their own to my application, insert them own domain name and i can map the domain name to their subdomain.

For example, they have a subdomain called mappable.example.com and they have a domain name called mappable.com

I have two questions:
1. How do you create a subdomain for them in php and/or nodejs called mappable.example.com
2. How do you map the domain name to mappable.com

I'm using nginx as a web server. Do I have to use php or nodejs to manually edit the nginx config files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you own example.com, they own mappable.com, and you want to allow them to use their domain mappable.com to access your subdomain mappable.example.com hosted on your server.

There are a few steps you'll need to do for this.

- Set up wildcard DNS with your domain registrar so that all sub-domains will come to your one server.
- Set up wildcard domain handling in nginx's conf on your one server so that all requests are sent to your code. You can do this using an underscore as the server name to make it the default server.
- In your PHP code, you can check the headers to determine what domain the request is coming in through. Do a dump of $_SERVER to see what's in there. You will then know if the request came to mappable.com, mappable.example.com, etc...

Once you are in PHP with the domain or subdomain that was requested, you can act accordingly. You'll want to store the mapping of domain to subdomain in a database most likely. Additionally, you'll have to tell your users that they need to set up a cname, for example a cname of "mappable.com" to "mappable.example.com".

I think that should do what you need.